# java skeleton code from design class diagram. Remove error

Tags: java, class-design, class-diagram

I was trying to write Java code for this design class Diagram. This question came in past exams.

I couldn't properly understand the relation of **FullTimeStudent and PartTimeStudent with PHDprogram**. If there is any other mistake in my code do correct me.

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
class student{ 
 int registration;
 String name;
 public void setName ( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
 }
}

class FullTimeStudent extends student{}
class PartTimeStudent extends student{}

interface course{  
 void setInstructorName(String name);
}

 class PhdCourse implements course{
  int courseCode;
  String coursename;
  String courseArea;
  String courseInstructor;
  @Override
  public void setInstructorName (String name) { this.courseInstructor = name;
  }
 }
 class PHDTheasis{ int code; String topic; String area; }

 class PHDprogram{
   FullTimeStudent ft;
   PartTimeStudent pt;
   int deptcode;
   public void registerCourse(PhdCourse c){}
   public void registerTheasis(PHDTheasis t){}

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is image from Wikipedia and other answer from stackoverflow [Direction of the association arrow in UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906386/direction-of-the-association-arrow-in-uml-class-diagrams/41748622#41748622)

[image: uml]

Summarizing this two sources your code should look next way

```
class PHDprogram {
   List<FullTimeStudent> ft;
   PartTimeStudent pt;
   ...
}
```

And optionally you can add relation from FullTimeStudent and PartTimeStudent sides

```
class PartTimeStudent {
    PHDprogram phdProgram;
}

class FullTimeStudent {
    PHDprogram phdProgram;
}
```